# Removing comments for cleanup beyond moderation is unhelpful

Tags: discussion

Interesting/important comments were removed from this discussion:

[How to pretty print XML from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java/139096#139096)

I agree comments need moderation, but moderation shouldn't remove explanation or clarification about the code sample itself, one of which specifically noted why this sample is just code instead of a class, after it was edited many many times to change it into some bloated mess.

Those kind of discussions shouldn't happen in the answer, but should be safe from overly zealous moderation in comments.

Comment: _interesting/important comments_ like what? Do you have screenshot of those or can you add few of them

Comment: Only moderators can see the deleted comments?

Comment: Of course I've no screenshot, why would I cap my own comment history? I didn't even know there were comment purges until this day.

Comment: There's 6 deleted comments on the link you've provided. They were flagged as obsolete and were deleted as such on July 4th.

Comment: If things are important/interesting they should be added as an edit or answer. You should always treat comments as a thing which can be deleted and should be used for clarifications etc.

Comment: @Hayt, the key word being *should*.  In practice, important information often does exist in comments, and deleting the thread means that this information appears nowhere.

Comment: @dan1111 hmm... then deleting more comments should raise more awareness to this and maybe change habits. *thinking* would result in loss of information though :(

Comment: Interesting comments do not exists. important comments , if they add anything to the post, should be edited into it

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to understand that comments are, and have always been, ephemeral

From [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

> ## How do comments work?
>
> Comments exist so that users can talk about questions and answers without posting new answers that do not actually answer their parent questions. Comments are often used to ask for clarification on, suggest corrections to and provide meta-information about posts.
>
> Comments are intentionally short, having maximum length of 600 characters, and allow only limited markup. URLs in comments automatically become hyperlinks. Each user may post only one comment every 15 seconds.
>
> **Comments are disposable: unlike posts, there's no revision history, and they can be deleted without warning by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags.**

Comment: Ok, but this is kind of question begging: this may be the policy but why is it so?  In particular what is the justification for deleting comments?

Comment: @dan1111 Stack Overflow is about **questions** and **answers**. The [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) even states `Ask questions, get answers, no distractions. This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.` Comments are, by their nature, chit-chatty. So if comments aren't useful anymore (or they were never useful) they can be deleted by mods or enough flags

Comment: I agree though that useful comments too often get sucked up in this.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you have x100 enough reputation to edit "that useful comment" in the post if you see one :)... As well as anyone who flags comment obsolete is presumably responsible to make sure the comment is indeed obsolete (covered in question/no longer relevant/whatever).

Comment: @Alexei not every comment is fit to be edited into an answer, by far. A good comment discussion on an answer's limitations can be worth its weight in gold.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In this case the comment appears to be an explanation for why it's important that certain information *not* be included in the answer, so obviously that can't be included in the answer.